# 'npm run watch' or 'dev' not working anymore in my computer (Laravel project), Error : '[webpack-cli] RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded'

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, npm, dotenv

I have been working on a website (using Laravel) recently, and since yesterday I have been working on JavaScript code (to implement Meilisearch). 

For this, I recently added the 'dotenv' library with node, because I need to get a variable in my .env file for the security key.

But today, after modifying the code, I did `npm run dev` and `npm run watch` but neither worked:\
The error message is this:\

> [webpack-cli] RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded  
> at RegExp.exec () 
> at C:\ ... \ ...\project\node_modules\dotenv-expand\lib\main.js:11:49 
> at Array.reduce () 
> at interpolate (C:\ ... \ ...\project\node_modules\dotenv-expand\lib\main.js:10:20) 
> at C:\ ... \ ...\project\node_modules\dotenv-expand\lib\main.js:26:17 
> at Array.reduce () 
> at interpolate (C:\ ... \ ...\project\node_modules\dotenv-expand\lib\main.js:10:20) 
> at C:\ ... \ ...\project\node_modules\dotenv-expand\lib\main.js:26:17 
> at Array.reduce () 
> at interpolate (C:\ ... \ ...\project\node_modules\dotenv-expand\lib\main.js:10:20)

[Error message in VScode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9bsL.png) 

I don't understand what the problem is here, especially because it seems to be only on my computer that it does that (I tried running the command with an other computer and it doesn't display this error).

Do you guys have an idea of what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleted your node_modules folder and then running NPM install and NPM run dev.

Comment: I have tried this, but it still displays the same error on npm run dev ..

Comment: @axja_shrk Did you get this fixed in the end? I've started running into this issue, interestingly right after installing `@meilisearch/instant-meilisearch`

I've now uninstalled the package and reverted package & package.json, removed node_modules and reinstalled yet still getting the same issue...

Comment: I've just solved my problem. I was being stupid. In my .env file I exposed a couple of mix variables that were self referencing, doh!